# В intellij idea не отображаются комментарии когда переходишь в классы стандартной библиотеки Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, комментарии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Неужели это реализовано только в ultimate версии?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия идеи IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-192.6603.28, built on September 6, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.56 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 972M
Cores: 8
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins:

Comment: Установите JDK, а не JRE

Comment: @Tsyklop Специально для Вас добавил скриншот.

Comment: @jewbaka, там же сверху написано, что это декомпилированный код, а не исходник, в нем нет (и не может быть) комментариев.

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет исходников для SDK (только уже скомиплированные в байткод классы). Когда вы смотрите в них, вы, по сути, видите попытку Intellij "раскомпилировать" эти классы. Потому сверху и есть предупреждение.

В настройках SDK можно добавить путь к исходникам. Как на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]